# Mazda Air Mass Meter - where can I buy one?

Tags: electrical, parts, mazda

I have a 1993 Mazda 323 estate (GLXI 1.6l petrol).
It's not been terribly reliable and has suffered from inconsistent idle - sometimes idling fast (~1500 rpm) and sometimes erratically and sometimes cutting out when stopped at lights.
The last mechanic I took it to said it was probably a problem with the air mass meter - he did some 'bodges' on it to try and get it working but the car has still failed to start on one occasion. It seems to start and drive ok at the moment, but I'm not sure how much longer it will continue to do so!

Is this likely a problem with the air mass meter or is it likely to be something else?

Also, does anyone know where I could get hold of a new one? (I'm based in the UK)

Comment: Have you checked for trouble codes?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Mazda, but some manufacturers still stock parts for older vehicles - it might be worth asking at the parts desk at your nearest dealer.

It's not the sort of part I'd expect a normal motor factor to stock, although they might still be able to get hold of one. Your best bet is probably to try one of the bigger parts chains such as [eurocarparts](http://www.eurocarparts.com/) (who, despite the name, also sell bits of japanese cars), [unipart](http://www.unipart.co.uk/wps/wcm/connect/unipart/unipartgroup/admin/uabranchlist) or [camberley auto factors](http://www.camberleyautofactors.com/home/index.php) (the latter is local to the Berkshire/Hampshire/Surrey area, but I think they do mail order)

Answer (score 1):

Like this [one](http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/search/?N=0&Nr=AND%28wpn_tl_name%3aEngine%20&%20Drivetrain,wpn_cat_name%3aFuel%20Systems%20&%20Components,wpn_scat_name%3aMAP%20Sensors%20&%20Components%29)? Not sure if your models match up to American ones, but this site might help. Hopefully they ship internationally.

Comment: Your link has expired - you might want to put the part number in the answer.

Comment: Go 1993, Mazda, 323, Any model, 1.6L, Air Intake, Mass Air Sensors.
Should see "Home>Engine & Drivetrain>Air Filters & Intake Systems>Mass Air Flow Sensors & Components" at top.